# find_one method returns keyerror

Tags: python-3.6, pymongo

Here's my code

```py
@classmethod
def get_by_email(cls, email):
    data = Database.find_one("users", {'email': email})
    if data is not None:
        return cls(**data)
```

output:

> KeyError: 'email'

The relevant document is present in mongodb

```
db.users.findOne({"email": "test@test.com"})

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e22fbde0cef633ad86a736f"),
    "email" : "test@test.com",
    "password" : "password"
}
```

Now i am not sure what i am doing wrong with this code.
Any suggestions please. i am using python 3.6

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `collection` directly instead of providing the `collection` name to the database. Like below:

```py
@classmethod
def get_by_email(cls, email):
    data = Database.users.find_one({'email': email})
    if data is not None:
        return cls(**data)
```

or similarly:

```py
@classmethod
def get_by_email(cls, email):
    data = Database['users'].find_one({'email': email})
    if data is not None:
        return cls(**data)
```

Comment: Thanks guys, but I could not get it to work

I have defined a function in database.py as such

{
    @staticmethod
    def find_one(collection, query):
        return Database.DATABASE[collection].find_one(query)
}

and I am calling it in the other code, had sorted out this issue once by using find() but this time it is a requirement to have just one record returned since I am checking user id exists or not.

sorry I tried to sort the code but being a newb I am unable to

Comment: so I think you should call your `Database.find_one` function like `Database.find_one('users', {'email': email})`

Comment: tried it as you have mentioned but still same key error for 'email'

Comment: Update: checked with another email and it worked perfectly without any issues but if I use test@test.com it gives me an error. now that's frustrating

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:
Corrected thanks to n1rna

[find_one()](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.find_one) requires a `dict` parameter. Try:

```
data = Database.users.find_one({'email': email})
```

Comment: I believe this will throw a `TypeError` for this `dict` is not hashable.

Comment: Thanks yes I should have actually run it to test :) Answer edited.